# How do I get the move function to work in my game?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Get home</title>

  <style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    td {
      border: solid 1px #888;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: calc(30px/4.0 + 1px);
      text-align: center;
    }

    .cell0 {
      background: #88ff99;
    }

    .cell1 {
      background: #116615;
    }

    .player {
      background: #e11;
    }

    .home {
      background: white;
    }

    .status {
      font-size: 15pt;
      font-family: Arial;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    //  Will be initialised to a 2-dimensional array
    var gameBoard = [];

    // Size of game
    var size = 10;

    // Current fuel and supply
    var fuel = 20;
    var supply = 0;

    // Current position of player (start in the bottom-right)
    var positionX = size - 1;
    var positionY = size - 1;

    // Whether we are playing the game
    var playing = true;

    // Use this function to make a move where x and y represent the direction of
    // a move, e.g.
    //    move(-1, 0) means going left
    //    move(1, 0) means going right
    //    move(0, -1) means going up
    //    move(0, 1) means going down
    function move(x, y) {
      //
      if (positionX + x < size && positionX + x >= 0 &&
        positionY + y < size && positionY + y >= 0) {
        // Move is within the board

      

      }
    }

    // Use this function to update the status
    function updateStatus() {
      document.getElementById("fuel").innerHTML = fuel;
      document.getElementById("store").innerHTML = supply;
    }

    function setup() {
      // Set the gameboard to be empty
      gameBoard = [];

      var board = document.getElementById("board");

      for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        // Create a new row of the game
        var htmlRow = document.createElement("tr");
        board.appendChild(htmlRow);
        var row = []

        for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
          // Chose a random type of cell
          var type = Math.round(Math.random());
          var cell = document.createElement("td");
          cell.className = "cell" + type;

          // Add the cell to the row
          htmlRow.appendChild(cell);
          row.push(cell);
        }

        gameBoard.push(row);
      }

      // Setup the player
      gameBoard[size-1][size-1].className = "player";

      // Setup the home
      gameBoard[0][0].className = "home";
      gameBoard[0][0].innerHTML = "HOME";

      // Register the listener and update the state
      updateStatus();
      document.body.addEventListener("keydown", keyEvent);
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body onLoad="setup();">

  <div class="status">Fuel: <span id="fuel"></div>
  <div class="status">Store: <span id="store"></div>

  <table id="board"></table>

  <div class="status" id="outcome"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm creating a simple game on HTML, and I can't think of how to get the move function to work, while it automatically updates the game and the map, is anyone able to help. I'm new to coding and I genuinely cant fathom what code to put in to make the move function work, whether it be using arrow keys or creating buttons to make the entity move.

Comment: I am looking this over and two things that immediately stand out: `keyEvent` is not defined, also you did not close your `span` html tags

Comment: It may help you get answers on stack overflow in the future if you can list the specific error you are having trouble with rather than asking an open ended question that could be accomplished many ways. When you get your game working as intended I would encourage you to visit [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Without making too many changes to the way you have things set up, I added a function that will add the "player" class to elements based on "wsad" or arrow key presses.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Get home</title>
  <style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    td {
      border: solid 1px #888;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: calc(30px/4.0 + 1px);
      text-align: center;
    }
    .cell0 {
      background: #88ff99;
    }
    .cell1 {
      background: #116615;
    }
    .player {
      background: #e11;
    }
    .home {
      background: white;
    }
    .status {
      font-size: 15pt;
      font-family: Arial;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    //  Will be initialised to a 2-dimensional array
    var gameBoard = [];

    // Size of game
    var size = 10;

    // Current fuel and supply
    var fuel = 20;
    var supply = 0;

    // Current position of player (start in the bottom-right)
    var positionX = size - 1;
    var positionY = size - 1;

    // Whether we are playing the game
    var playing = true;

    function move(direction) {
      let x = positionX;
      let y = positionY;
      switch (direction) {
        case "left":
          x--;
          break;
        case "right":
          x++;
          break;
        case "up":
          y--;
          break;
        case "down":
          y++;
          break;
      }
      const validMove =
        x < size &&
        x >= 0 &&
        y < size &&
        y >= 0;
      if (!validMove) return console.error(
        "What are you trying to do?" + "\n" +
        "Break the implied rules of a game?" + "\n" +
        "I expect more from you" + "\n" +
        "That's a wall you dummy!"
      );
      positionX = x;
      positionY = y;
      gameBoard[y][x].classList.add("player");
    }

    // Use this function to update the status
    function updateStatus() {
      document.getElementById("fuel").innerText = fuel;
      document.getElementById("store").innerText = supply;
    }

    function keyEvent(e) {
      const keyMoveDict = {
        "ArrowLeft": "left",
        "ArrowRight": "right",
        "ArrowUp": "up",
        "ArrowDown": "down",
        "a": "left",
        "d": "right",
        "w": "up",
        "s": "down",
      }
      const movement = keyMoveDict[e.key];
      if (movement) move(movement);
    }

    function setup() {
      // Set the gameboard to be empty
      gameBoard = [];

      var board = document.getElementById("board");
      for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // Create a new row of the game
        var htmlRow = document.createElement("tr");
        board.appendChild(htmlRow);
        var row = []

        for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
          // Chose a random type of cell
          var type = Math.round(Math.random());
          var cell = document.createElement("td");
          cell.className = "cell" + type;

          // Add the cell to the row
          htmlRow.appendChild(cell);
          row.push(cell);
        }

        gameBoard.push(row);
      }

      // Setup the player
      gameBoard[size-1][size-1].className = "player";

      // Setup the home
      gameBoard[0][0].className = "home";
      gameBoard[0][0].innerHTML = "HOME";

      // Register the listener and update the state
      updateStatus();
      document.body.addEventListener("keydown", keyEvent);
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body onLoad="setup();">

  <div class="status">Fuel: <span id="fuel"></span></div>
  <div class="status">Store: <span id="store"></span></div>

  <table id="board"></table>

  <div class="status" id="outcome"></div>

</body>

</html>
```